# analysis of a probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

if we have 100 people in total and we are to select each person randomly every day.what is the probability that after 3 years(1095 days) each person has been selected at least once.
for eg. on the first day, the probability will be 1  and second day it will go on decreasinglike  99/100 and so on.
this was actually a puzzle but I wanted to do some probability analysis.

Comment: kindly include what you have tried.

Comment: well i am kind of confused to be honest.initially i thought it would be 1*99/100*98/100*.....1/100 from there on 1/100 for the remaining days.but i don't think that is correct by any means.

Comment: @anmolhans you are missing a lot of cases with that formula.

Comment: yes, I know this formula is flawed.this is why I was looking for someone to help me with the analysis.   this will help me get clearer understanding of probability as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many functions from $[1,1095]$ to $[1,100]$ are surjective?
Let $N$ be this number then your probability is equal to
$$p=\frac{N}{100^{1095}}=\frac{100!S(1095,100)}{100^{1095}}.$$
Where $S(n,k)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

If you are looking for an approximation value of $p$ then for $k$ fixed 
$$k!S(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(k-j)^n\approx k^n-k(k-1)^{n}.$$
and therefore 
$$p\approx \frac{k^n-k(k-1)^{n}}{k^{n}}=1-k(1-1/k)^{n}\approx1-ke^{-n/k}\approx 0.9982442$$
where $k=100$ and $n=1095$. Note that the correct value of $p$ is $0.9983396$.

Comment: i studied "onto" and "into" functions in my high school and i don't remember much about them.i will take my chances so is "N=1095"?because each day at least one person will get selected .so there will always be 1095 mapping from x to y. and we are considering that all of them got selected at least once so it obeys the rules of surjection.please tell me the answer

Comment: i am pretty sure i have never studied about stirling number of second kind but i will try to learn about it.

Comment: I am not looking for exact value numerically which will almost be impossible  but the fraction should be exact at least.

Comment: @anmol hans See my edited answer.

Comment: wow, you are the coolest mathematician I have ever known.i will learn about Stirling number and come back to be on board.thanks by the way.

Comment: @anmol hans  I corrected a few details. Let me know if you have further doubts

Answer (score 0):

First, you should calcule the probability of the event that $n$-th person is never selected. Let's denote as $A_n$ this event.

Then, the probability of somebody not being picked any day is 
$$P(A_1) + P(A_2) + \cdots + P(A_{100})$$
What is its complementary event? Such event would have probability,
$$1-\sum^n P(A_n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Without replacement everyone gets picked in the first 100 days. With replacement, the probability of any one person being selected (assuming IID) is:

$1-(1-\frac{1}{100})^{1095}$

Since there are 100 people:

$(1-(0.99)^{1095})^{100} = 0.98339722$